# Unable to link dynamic library : Compiling through Xcode make

Tags: c++, makefile, xcode7, dylib

My project structure is as follows:
Project>src>main.cpp

The main.cpp calls methods which have a dependancy to a dynamic library (.dylib). In my /usr/local/bin the dynamic library has the name libgismo.dylib but it is an alias which points to libgismo.0.8.1.dylib

My make file is:

```
# Targets
SRCPATH = ./src
GISMOPATH = /usr/local/include/gismo

CXX = g++
INCLUDE = -I/usr/local/bin -I/usr/local/include -I$(GISMOPATH) -I/usr/local/lib
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib
LIBS = -libgismo
all: main
main : $(SRCPATH)/main.cpp
     @$(CXX) $(INCLUDE) $(SRCPATH)/main.cpp -o main $(DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH) $(LIBS)
     $(info Compiling main)
clean :
     @rm main
```

But when I build it through Xcode the following error is generated:

```
ld: library not found for -libgismo.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2
```

The output to:

```
$ make -n
```

is

```
g++ -I/usr/local/bin -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/gismo -I/usr/local/lib ./src/main.cpp -o main -L/usr/local/lib/ -libgismo
```

AND

```
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/*gismo*
```

is

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     1337 May 14 11:35 /usr/local/lib/gismoConfig.cmake
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel      366 May 14 11:35 /usr/local/lib/gismoConfigVersion.cmake
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     3900 May 14 11:34 /usr/local/lib/gismoUse.cmake
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  9195544 May 14 11:52 /usr/local/lib/libgismo.0.8.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       20 May 12 10:23 /usr/local/lib/libgismo.0.dylib -> libgismo.0.8.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel       16 May 12 10:23 /usr/local/lib/libgismo.dylib -> libgismo.0.dylib
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: How is your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` defined?

Comment: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH = -L/usr/local/lib/ @jiveturkey

Comment: for now just add the `-n` flag to your make command and see what it would execute.

Comment: g++ -I/usr/local/bin -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/gismo -I/usr/local/lib ./src/main.cpp -o main -L/usr/local/lib/ -libgismo

;Is the output I get; @jiveturkey

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments area - instead click `edit` under your question and update the question. Please show the output of the command `ls -l /usr/local/lib/*gismo*`

Comment: @MarkSetchell , edited the question in response to your comments and inputs

Comment: Try changing `LIBS = -libgismo` to `LIBS = -lgismo`

Comment: @MarkSetchell this worked!